# SQL count values in table and only return 5 highest

Tags: php, mysql

So, I'm working on a simple search page on my website and I'm trying to select only the most relevant information.

In order to do that, I'd like to select data from 2 different tables. But I'd only like to select data that is matched to the search query.

Now, here's the fun part. I'd only like to select the data with the most occurrences of $variable and then sort that data from highest to lowest and then limit the amount of results(to something 1,000 or 2,000)

To ask it in lesser words/code form. I'd like to do something like this in SQL(run by PHP)

```
$query = ["search","me","please"];
$maxData = 1500;
foreach($query as $value){
   //SQL start(Part I need help on)
   $res1 = SELECT * from table1 WHERE column LIKE %$value% AND return columns with highest times $value appears LIMIT $maxData

   $res2 = SELECT * from table2 WHERE column1,column2,column3 LIKE %$value% AND return columns with highest times $value appears LIMIT $maxData

}
```

I'd like it to count how many times the searched variable appears in the column and return the times in order from highest count to lowest

Is all of this possible in SQL alone?

Also, if my question is unclear or hard to understand, Please say so.

Comment: you will either get a match or not, so i dont understand 'columns with most matches'

Comment: @dagon when I say match, I'm trying to count how many times that "match" occurs. I'll edit that part real quick.

Comment: i think we need real world data (and expected results) if your looking to search with real rankings you usually need to look at full-text searches

Comment: @dagon I could upload an example of my real database with real results that I'm looking for, should I upload it here or link to it somewhere?

Comment: A clearer question, of far fewer words, could be assembled by way of a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use mysql `fulltext` search. in this case you will get a score per result.

See more details [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)

Comment: link only answers are discouraged

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using sql  by using group by statement and by using of a helper table.

Create table tbl_search with one column search_term as varchar.

This table will be truncated and refill with search terms each time the query is executed.

```
Select * from
(Select search_term, count(*) as hits 
from table1 , tbl_search 
where table1.column like '%' + tbl_search.search_term +'%'
Group by tbl_search.search_term) as z1
Order by hits
```

Index the tbl_search.search_term to help query performance.

Comment: I tried to do this, but don't quite understand how it works. Can you provide an example?